# Python/Pandas syntax for creating a new dataframe by comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some string comparisons on two columns in a df, but when i go to assign the results to a new dataframe I only get 1 column with the boolean result of the comparison:

```
N=df['pair2'].str.split('_').str[1]!=df['pair1'].str.split('_').str[1]
```

N contains:

```
 True
 False
 ....
```

Where as I just want the entire original df minus the rows where the string comparison is TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N is a boolean array. `df[N]` gives you rows where N is True. If you want to remove those elements, you need `df[~N]`.